# Add video tag to youtube link fron content

Tags: content, youtube

I have variable `$post->post_content` that return me detail of post and some video URL from YouTube.

I need to remove any text from `$post->post_content` else YouTube link, And add to YouTube likn this tag

```
<video>YouTube_URL</video>
```

the `content` like :-

```
At this instant, while Daggoo, on the summit of the head, was clearing the whip—which had somehow got foul of the great cutting tackles—a sharp cracking noise was heard; and to the unspeakable horror of all, one of the two enormous hooks suspending the head tore out, and with a vast vibration the enormous mass sideways swung, till the drunk ship reeled and shook as if smitten by an iceberg. The one remaining hook, upon which the entire strain now depended, seemed every instant to be on the point of giving way; an event still more likely from the violent motions of the head.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEreM0ZKY18
```

and some time like :-

```
أسر شعار اسبوعين الدولارات من, شرسة أعلنت اندلاع إذ هذا. وبعد الثالث أوكيناوا ما بين, الحصار الأمامية بـ عدد. ذات بقعة فمرّ إذ, أخذ كل بالحرب وسمّيت المانيا. و فصل بمباركة المقيتة, أملاً الحصار المتاخمة من عدد. بزمام أثره، التبرعات تم بعد, الجيش خصوصا كانتا ان دار.

    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEreM0ZKY18
```

How can do that.?

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this:

```
$string =  "Some text before the link http://www.youtube.com/?123 some text after the link";
preg_match_all('@(https?://www\.?youtube.com/.[^\s.,"\']+)@i', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

In your case would be something similar to this:

```
preg_match_all('@(https?://www\.?youtube.com/.[^\s.,"\']+)@i', $post->post_content, $matches);
foreach($matches as $match){
    echo "<video>$match</video>";
}
```

Comment: thank you, but i test it and not work with me, its not print any thing

Comment: What's inside your post? How does it look like? The output of $post->post_content

Comment: i edit my post, see it

Comment: I have edited my answer with a new regex code

Comment: its same old code :-)

Comment: It's different, see here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/193283/revisions

Comment: sorry, but still not work

Comment: Maybe it's because $post->post_content has html entities encoded. Try wrapping html_entity_decode($post->post_content) in the preg_match_all

Comment: i do that but not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25444/discussion-between-marcovega-and-zamalek-man).

Comment: i edit your code to echo "<video>$match[1]</video>"; but why show 2 video if its have one link ?

Comment: Do a print_r($matches) after the preg_match and get the variable you need.

Comment: print_r not work with me because i use echo, when test it out the file and use print_r , its show my duplicate